# iOS SDWebImage - How to properly handle retina images on different devices?

Tags: ios, retina-display, ios-universal-app, sdwebimage

I am using the SDWebImage library for image caching in my apps, but haven't been able to get retina images to display properly.

I know there has been a lot of conversation about the downloading of retina images on the github page, but can't really tell if it has been fully resolved and there isn't any "official" how-to.

Because my app is universal, there will be 4 variations of each images I download. Here is an example:

- iPhone: http://www.DOMAIN.com/my-image~iphone.png
- iPhone Retina: http://www.DOMAIN.com/my-image@2x~iphone.png
- iPad: http://www.DOMAIN.com/my-image~ipad.png
- iPad Retina: http://www.DOMAIN.com/my-image@2x~ipad.png

What is the proper method to download these images and have the device use the correct one with SDWebImage?

I tried downloading the @2x-iphone.png image on my iPhone 5, but it displayed the image blown up and pixelated, as if it didn't know it was an @2x image.

What is the proper method to handle retina images with multiple device types?

Answer (score 4):

First, the cause - UIImage doesn't know if image is retina image or regular image. When you call `-[UIImage imageNamed:]` it calls `-[UIImage imageWithData:scale:]` with appropriate value for scale.

Your issue is caused by a bug in SDWebImage. See [source](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/SDWebImageCompat.m#L42). Please go ahead and [file a bug](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues) if it doesn't already exist.

The problem is SDWebImage only looks for @2x.png/jpeg file names to determine is it's a retina image or not. You can go ahead and fix that function to also check for @2x~iphone.png/@2x~ipad.png file names.

Alternatively, if you don't want to touch SDWebImage code, in your `webImageManager:didFinishWithImage:forURL:userInfo:` callback, check if the file name is a retina image and if so, do this:

```
image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: image.CGImage scale: [UIScreen mainScreen].scale]
```

Comment: Thanks! This got me pointed in the right direction! It was an issue with the filter string being used to detect retina. See my below answer.

Comment: @Mar0ux Well done, thanks! But please edit your answer, because there is a small mistake. imageWithData won't accept image.CGImage (it should be NSData type) so it probably should be [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp].

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that SDWebImage was only using the below filter to determine if a image was retina or not (located in SDWebImageCompat.m):

```
NSRange range = [path rangeOfString:@"@2x." options:0 range:NSMakeRange(path.length - 8, 5)];
```

Because it was searching only for "@2x." (note the period) and only if it fell at the end of the string so images with names like "my-image@2x~iphone.png" would not be detected as retina.

Updated the code to search entire image url for "@2x". Only concern with this is you cannot use "@2x" anywhere else in the url (but what developer ever uses that kind of naming convention?):

```
NSRange range = [path rangeOfString:@"@2x" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,path.length)];
```

I also submitted a pull request on the SDWebImage GitHub page (https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/pull/370)